# Characterization for convergence in measure in sets of finite measure

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, convergence-divergence

Let $(\Omega,\mathcal{A}, \mu)$ be a $\sigma-$finite measure space where $\Omega = \bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty}A_n$, $0<\mu(A_n)< + \infty$.
We denote by $\mathcal{M}$ the set of all extended scalar-valued   $\mu-$measurable functions $f$ defined on $\Omega$ which are finite $\mu-$almost everywhere.

The function $d: \mathcal{M} \times \mathcal{M} \rightarrow [0,+ \infty)$:
\begin{equation} \label{eqn24} 
d(f,g) = \sum_{n=1}^{+ \infty} \frac{1}{2^n} \cdot \frac{1}{\mu(A_n)} \cdot \int_{A_n} \frac{|f-g|}{1+ |f-g|} d \mu
\end{equation}
defines a metric on $\mathcal{M}$.

I want to prove that if $f_m \rightarrow f$ in measure in sets of finite measure then $f_m \rightarrow f$ in $(\mathcal{M},d)$.

**My attempt**

Let $\varepsilon>0$.
\begin{equation*}
\begin{split}
d(f_m,f) &= \sum_{n=1}^{+ \infty} \frac{1}{2^n} \cdot \frac{1}{\mu(A_n)} \cdot \int_{A_n} \frac{|f_m-f|}{1+ |f_m-f|} d \mu\\
&= S_{1,m}+S_{2,m}
\end{split}
\end{equation*}
where $$S_{1,m}=\sum_{n=1}^{+ \infty} \frac{1}{2^n} \cdot \frac{1}{\mu(A_n)} \cdot \int_{A_n \cap \{|f_m-f| <\varepsilon\}} \frac{|f_m-f|}{1+ |f_m-f|} d \mu$$ and $$S_{2,m}=\sum_{n=1}^{+ \infty} \frac{1}{2^n} \cdot \frac{1}{\mu(A_n)} \cdot \int_{A_n \cap \{|f_m-f| \geq \varepsilon\}} \frac{|f_m-f|}{1+ |f_m-f|} d \mu.$$
Then, since the function $\frac{x}{1+x}$ is increasing in $[0,+\infty)$, it follows that
\begin{equation*}
\begin{split}
\int_{A_n \cap \{|f_m-f| <\varepsilon\}} \frac{|f_m-f|}{1+ |f_m-f|} d \mu &\leq \frac{\varepsilon}{1+\varepsilon} \cdot \mu(A_n \cap \{|f_m-f|<\varepsilon \})\\
&\leq \varepsilon \cdot \mu(A_n \cap \{|f_m-f|<\varepsilon \}).
\end{split}
\end{equation*}
Thus,
\begin{equation*}
\begin{split}
S_{1,m} &\leq \sum_{n=1}^{+ \infty} \frac{1}{2^n} \cdot \frac{1}{\mu(A_n)} \cdot \varepsilon \cdot \mu(A_n \cap \{|f_m-f|<\varepsilon \})\\
&\leq  \sum_{n=1}^{+ \infty} \frac{1}{2^n} \cdot \varepsilon\\
&= \varepsilon.
\end{split}
\end{equation*}
Also,
\begin{equation*}
\begin{split}
S_{2,m} &\leq \sum_{n=1}^{+ \infty} \frac{1}{2^n} \cdot \frac{1}{\mu(A_n)} \cdot \mu(A_n \cap \{|f_m-f| \geq \varepsilon \})
\end{split}
\end{equation*}
By assumption, $\lim_{m \rightarrow + \infty} \mu(A_n \cap \{|f_m-f| \geq \varepsilon \})=0$ but I am not sure how to apply this to the above situation to conclude that $\lim_{m \rightarrow + \infty} S_{2,m}=0$.

Comment: How about dominated convergence theorem?

Comment: @ParesseuxNguyen How can DCT be used here?

Comment: $$\lim_m \int_{A_n} \frac{ |f_m-f|}{1+|f_n-f|}d\mu=0$$ $$\frac{1}{\mu(A_n)} \int_{A_n} \frac{ |f_m-f|}{1+|f_m-f|}d\mu \le 1$$

Comment: In your argument, you can use DCT to conclude by noticing that $\lim_m \mu( |f_m-f|>\epsilon)=0$

Comment: @ParesseuxNguyen The fact that $\lim_{m \rightarrow + \infty} \mu(A_n \cap \{|f_m-f| \geq \varepsilon \})=0$ I've already written in the last part of my proof. The question is if you can move the $\lim_{m}$ inside the series and if DCT justifies that I don't see how.

Comment: so I gave the second inequality ...